# My webscraper is returning an empty list when im using the correct CSS selector

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am attempting to scrape some data off of this particular url by using selenium or scrapy.

ive scraped other pages without issue, however when it comes to these particular urls the info im trying to scrape into a list is returning empty. I've used scrapy then moved on to using selenium but the result is the same. I'm also using pycharm and chromedriver.

The info im looking for in particular is all the different phone models on 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices'. I print the list only to find out nothing was scraped from the site or rather scrape is successful but nothing was returned.

The same occurs when i try to scrape anything from here as well:

https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786074&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2015GB

```
from selenium import webdriver

#open chrome browser and navigate to the webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")

#extract the names of the phones
phones = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.jXeFbj')

#counts phone and its model
for element in range(len(phones)):
    numPhone = int(element) + 1
    print("phone "+ str(numPhone) +" : " + phones[element].text)


#number of phones in total
sizeOfList = len(phones)
print(sizeOfList)
```

Whats supposed to happen is pull all the model names of the phones into a list.

phones = ['iPhone XS Max', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone XR',...]

Comment: Try adding EC so that the script will wait for the items to be loaded. `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".jXeFbj")))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, what might be happenning is that you get an empty list sometimes by sending the request to fast.

You can overcome this issue using WebDriverWait.

Here's code that you can uses will small improvements:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")

# get the list of phones
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
phones = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jXeFbj')))
numPhones = len(phones)

#prints the formatted output of each phone
for idx, phone in enumerate(phones):
    phone_name = phone.text
    print("phone " + str(idx) + " : " + phone_name)

print(numPhones)
```

Output 1:

```
phone 0 : iPhone XS Max
phone 1 : iPhone XS
phone 2 : iPhone XR
phone 3 : iPhone 8 Plus
phone 4 : iPhone 8
phone 5 : Galaxy S10+
...
```

Output 2:

```
27
```

Answer (score -1):

To to scrape the all the model names of the phones into a list in the form of **['iPhone XS Max', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone XR',...]** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")
  #using CSS_SELECTOR
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3[class^='deviceListItem__DeviceModel-']")))])
  #using XPATH
  #print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[starts-with(@class, 'deviceListItem__DeviceModel-')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['iPhone XS Max', 'iPhone XS', 'iPhone XR', 'iPhone 8 Plus', 'iPhone 8', 'Galaxy S10+', 'Galaxy S10', 'Galaxy S10e', 'Galaxy Tab A 8 LTE', 'Galaxy Note9', 'Galaxy S9', 'Galaxy A8', 'G7 Power', 'Moto E5 Play', 'Pixel 3a', 'Pixel 3', 'Pixel 3 XL', 'Z557', 'G7 ThinQ', 'P30 lite', 'Mate 20 Pro', 'X Power 3', 'G8 ThinQ', 'Q Stylo +', 'GoFLIP', 'Bring Your', 'Own Device']
  ```

Comment: @Lawrence_matei Can I get a feedback on this answer please?